# pass value of listbox items to select parameter

Tags: c#, listbox, objectdatasource

I have a form with a multi list box:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstAction" runat="server" Rows="3" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

I have a stored procedure that's getting data from an objectdatasource, when one value is passed it works ok

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsSalesSC" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="RapidFire.RFTableAdapters.USP_TOTAL_ORDERCALLSTableAdapter" OnSelecting="odsSalesSC_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lstAction" Name="action" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />                
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

But when a user select mulitple options I have build a string from the  selection that pass into a storedprocedure like where something in ('a','b','c').
How can I get the values from strAction to pass into my select parameter?

```
protected void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        String strAction = String.Empty;           
        foreach (ListItem liAction in lstAction.Items)
        {
            if (liAction.Selected)
            {
                strAction += "'" + liAction.Value + "',";
            }
        }
        strAction = strAction.Substring(0, strAction.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Please check the Storedprocedure it should have query in the where condition as in ('a','b') instead of = . if this solves ur problem please let me know i will add this as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
string strYourIDs = "";

int[] yourSelectedIndexes = ListBox.GetSelectedIndices();
for (int i = yourSelectedIndexes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    strYourIDs += ListBox.Items[yourSelectedIndexes[i]].Value + ",";
}

if (strYourIDs != "")
    strYourIDs = strYourIDs.TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray());
```

Grabs the selected indexes from the listbox then loops through and adds them to the comma delimitted, strYourIDs. Then cuts off the final comma at the end of the string. Now if three items were selected with value 1, 2, and 3 the string would look like "1,2,3". You can use that string in SQL by creating a split string function or something that splits those values and you can use them however you like.